# Allow us to export posts to ebook/pdf format

Tags: feature-request, posts, pdf

Wiki has this function now.  This is quite useful IMO as I want to print out one Q&A or maybe all the favorite topics I have collected over the years and then compile them into a book *stylishly*.  Any ideas?  Is this doable?

Comment: Feature requests on Meta can be downvoted in disagreement. Kind of a yay or nay vote. Perhaps someone doesn't see the value of or need for that.

Comment: You don't need SE to do anything to do this.  If you want to pull down the site's data and compile it into a book, you can do that.  The information is all there and freely accessible.

Comment: Then it must be a sharp disagreement. :) I'd like to know why he/she think this is a absolutely bad idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for a website.  Kinda like Pocket.  But with the ability to print out collected links.  Get on that, okay?  Call it Packet, and give me 20% of the profits.

Comment: @Daniel part of the problem is your "feature request" is not very complete.  Maybe you can explain why existing PDF creation tools are not sufficient.  There are a number of free PDF printing tools including some browsers that can do it without an external tool.  So you should be able to print out interesting posts yourself and create your own PDF Book.  Even though this seems small, it still requires developer effort, so it means this needs important enough to justify the cost and to justify not working on a different feature request.

Comment: Developer time is limited, and adding features costs money.  Some feature requests get downvotes because they don't seem to add enough value to offset the expense of creating them, especially if alternative (cost-free) solutions are already available.

Answer (score 4):

Start with [Stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com), and install a PDF print driver in your system. Install a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298) or [bookmarklet](http://www.stackprinter.com/) to enable a print button for each page.

If you want to further format the output of the data, you can use client side scripting to apply different formatting rules.  Alternately, get the [source](http://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter) of [Stackprinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite), add a PDF rendering engine on it, use a userscript to add a link/button to each page, and you can skip the pdf print driver.

Answer (score 2):

MarkSchoonover in this post ([Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow in eBook Format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213119/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-in-ebook-format)) announced the conclusion of a project that intends to do what you propose.

As to implement that on the network, I'm not sure if there would be clear benefits in that. Only a very small percentage of questions and answers are really that good to be "stored" as a .pdf archive. This being said, while the network doesn't have that functionality, you can do it youself, using any of the methods Adam and Mark have stated.